# Google Site Search廃止後の移行先について

Tags: google-api

Google Site Searchは2018年3月にサービス終了となるため、移行先を検討しています。

Googleカスタム検索であれば無料で使えますが、コーポレートサイトのサイト内検索のために導入しているため、他社広告が出るのはNGという案件です。

もし同じ境遇の方がいらっしゃれば、移行先のサービスを教えて頂けますでしょうか。